# How do I combined two styles in a single Grid cell?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I've tried different methods posted here and StackOverFlow and none seem to work. I basically have the following CSS:

```
.v-grid-cell.cellBackgroundColor {
    background-color: red;
}

.v-grid-cell.cellfontColor {
    color: green;
}
```

And for the code I have:

```
addColumn(MyData::getValue)
    .setStyleGenerator(data -> "cellBackgroundColor cellFontColor");
```

All this seems to do is use the last style and ignore the first one. I then saw [this post from the Vaadin forums which suggested putting a period between the two styles](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/15553757) but that didn't work either.

Basically how can I combine two different styles? And in case you're wondering why I'm not doing it in css it's because the combination is due to logic in the code which is not included in the sample code to simplify it.

Comment: Maybe because of the `F` case typo, `.v-grid-cell.cellfontColor` vs `cellFontColor`? Other than that it worked fine for me using your sample and Vaadin 8.5.1. Alternatively you can probably use the [_class css selector_](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) : `.v-grid-cell[class*="cellBackgroundColor"] {background-color: red;}`

Comment: I changed the actual code from the real code. That being said I checked for typos and didn't find any... Great catch though!

Comment: In that case, can you please share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) that reproduces your actual issue?